# Prevent Image from being resized using Javascript

Tags: javascript, velo

I'm putting together a site for work using Wix. Currently, the page I am working on has an image on it that is meant to be used by the user to find out what size of disposable gloves they should purchase.

The issue is this image is resized on computers with a smaller resolution. I need this picture to remain at its exact size no matter what the size of the desktop monitor.

Is there a way of accomplishing this through Javascript?

Layout should be visible by link. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new and it won't let me post an image. Example is in the link here:
https://ibb.co/0MJK6zs

Comment: Use `img.class-name { width: 100px !important!; min-width: 100px !important!; max-width: 100px !important! }` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have access to CSS/HTML on wix **(for this context)** so the only way you can control image dimensions is using the [fitMode](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/image/fitmode) property of the image.

Comment: You can add css/html on wix : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877549/how-to-add-custom-css-in-wix-website

Comment: @HenryLy I was talking in context to the question. You cannot alter the image using the HTML/CSS.

Comment: Hey @Shan! I realize I was wrong to downvote your answer since the fitMode did fix the issue. Anyway even though you don't have direct access to the HTML/CSS you could access the DOM to manipulate their style. Example from the doc. `$w("#myElement").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";`  Do correct me if this is incorrect though I know you have more experience in Wix.