# Using CodePen- How can I add my CSS to HTML for Wix?

Tags: html, css, velo

I am new to working with HTML *and* CSS.  I have used HTML code on Wix before, but have not tried to also include CSS.

I would like to create infinite scrolling text that outlines text on hover.  I found and customized a code on CodePen:

I added a photo of the codes I'm trying to use because the formatting was weird in this post.

[image: code snippet HTML and CSS]

I tried using  and  tags, but when I add it to Wix, it will not work.  At this time, I receive a list of the words I added with a hyperlink (that directs to nowhere), and the background color is the color I input for the text.  I have been at this for DAYS!! Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this link answer your question? https://studiok40.com/add-custom-css-in-wix-websites/

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add custom css in wix website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877549/how-to-add-custom-css-in-wix-website)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "You can do this by embedding inline styles to every page, via creating a chunk of custom css code contained between <style> and </style>."

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer!

You should be able to do this with basic html language.

```
<html>
<style>
</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You add the html bit between  and  and then between the two styles you put the CSS code and finally the  you put the JS (javascript) language.

Hope this helps! (It took me a good 5 hours to understand this).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).